# Using bokeh plotting with kafka streaming

Tags: java, python, apache-kafka, bokeh, apache-kafka-streams

Here is a problem I am stuck with presently.

Recently I have been exploring bokeh for plotting and kafka for streaming.
And I thought of making a sample live dashboard using both of them.

But the problem is I use bokeh with python and kafka stream api's with Java. Is there a way to use them together by any chance.

The only way I can see is both of them can be used with scala. But presently I don't want to get into scala.

Comment: You might be able to use some python/java "bridge" technology. But this would be a hand crafted solution. There is not official support for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try kafka-python. You can set up a simple consumer to read the data from your cluster.

Comment: Link for reference - https://github.com/Aakash282/kafka-bokeh-dashboard